# What is this variable referring to in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So what I am doing is trying to understand what const [,] or const [_,,,] does in this for of loop in typescript or javascript. What are these?

```
function getArr() {
    return ['a','b', 'c']
}

for (const [,] of getArr()) {
}

for (const [_,,,] of getArr()) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example both `for` loops will cause an errors. What you want in JS is called [*Destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). For example you have a function `getArr()` which returns an array, but you want to get (for some reason) only first array value. You can use *Destrictuing Assignment*.

```js
const [first, ...rest] = getArr();
console.log(first) // Will output: 'a'
console.log(rest) // Will output: ['b', 'c']
```

In your example, in the first loop you're trying to use *Destructing Assignment* on and variable, not an array, so error will happen. Just look how [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop works with arrays. Obviously in the second `for..of` loop you trying to do the same, but saving first array element in the variable by the name `_`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I were to change the variable name of the second loop to [,___], then I am essentially returning the rest of the destructed elements?

Comment: First, you can't use `Destructing Assignment` for the variable between keywords `const` and `of`, because this is how for-of loop works for Arrays in JS. There is always be currently iterating element of your Array (Iterable Object). It should be smth like
`for (const element of getArr()) {
  console.log(element) // Output will be: 'a' on first iteration, 'b' on the second, 'c'
...
}`

Comment: Second, if you use Destructing Assignment, like this `const [,___] = getArr()` you will skip first array element, and save second to the variable by the name `___`.

Comment: "*In your example both for loops will cause an errors*" no they don't: https://jsbin.com/xesagom/edit?js,console the syntax is valid as is the operation.

Comment: "*First, you can't use Destructing Assignment for the variable between keywords const and of, because this is how for-of loop works for Arrays in JS.*" of course you can use it. https://jsbin.com/cititir/1/edit?js,console That's *exactly* how loops and destructuring work - you can use array destructuring on anything which defines an iterator. A string *does* have an iterator. You can also destructure strings `const [first] = "hello"` is `"h"`.

Comment: @VLAZ, Of course! You're right. thanks for correction. I've tested both loops on array [1,2,3]. Numbers aren't iterable, so i've got an error `Uncaught TypeError: .for is not iterable`.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getArr() {
return ['a','b', 'c']
}



for (const item of getArr()) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

Try above code if you access return value from the function

Comment: So is the [,] and [,___] just a placeholder? What exactly are they and what is their usage? Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question very well.  Perhaps you could expand your explanation.